# Excluding form fields from keypress handler assigned to body

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keypress, onkeypress, event-propagation

I have a `keypress` handler on a web page assigned to the body element.  I really do want it to be active anywhere in the web page.  Or so I thought.  The `keypress` events in textual input forms also activate the body handler, which makes sense, but which I don't want.

Ideally, I'd like to keep the `keypress` handler assigned to the body element and somehow exclude just the input forms.  Is there any way I can stop the event at the input level and prevent it from propagating to body?  (Or is that even the right way to look at HTML DOM events?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It would be easier simply to check which element triggered the event in your keypress handler and filter out input elements:

```
document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
    if ( !/INPUT|TEXTAREA|SELECT|BUTTON/.test(target.nodeName) ) {
        // Do stuff
    }
};
```

Comment: Well, that was too obvious.  Thanks.