# Detect spacebar press when no text inputs are focused

Tags: javascript, html, input

I want to use JavaScript to detect when the spacebar is pressed. I want to exclude all events in which any input is focused. Is this possible with pure JS?

Note: The main point of this question is excluding all events in which an input is focused.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [respond to key press javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600892/respond-to-key-press-javascript)

Comment: The main point of this question is excluding all events in which an input is focused.

Comment: that other question is just a key press detection

Comment: So, more like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621346/excluding-form-fields-from-keypress-handler-assigned-to-body?

Comment: yes. thank you @Paul Roub. I hate when people are so quick to mark as duplicate without reading all the details.

Answer (score 7):

```
// capture keyboard input
document.onkeypress = function (e) {

    // check for spacebar press
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {

        // check if an input is currently in focus
        if (document.activeElement.nodeName.toLowerCase() != "input") {

            // prevent default spacebar event (scrolling to bottom)
            e.preventDefault();

            // do stuff you want ...
        }
    }
};
```

some other element to watch for spacebar focus:

- `textarea`
- `button`

Comment: I know the OP didn't mention it, but probably a good idea to exclude textarea too.

Comment: ... and `<button>`. A focussed button can be activated by pressing space. It's probably also better to reverse your tests — `e.keyCode === 32` is a much cheaper test, so do `document.activeElement.nodeName.toLowerCase() != "input"` only when a space is hit.